# Map how to change key value

Tags: java, android

It is possible to change value of particular key in java

```
   int increment = 0;
    if (tilesMap.containsKey('a'){
    int value = tilesMap.get('a')

// setting the increment value in 'a'

    increment ++;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
   int increment = 0;
    if (tilesMap.containsKey('a'){
    int value = tilesMap.get('a')

    tilesMap.put('a', ++value);

    increment ++;
    }
```

after `put`, old value will be removed, new value will be assigned

That's working well if you have `Map<Character, Integer>`.
If you have `Map<String, Integer>`, use `"a"` instead of `'a'`

Answer (score 0):

take attention. Your could could not work because of using "char" literal but "String" in the key of map.

This code would compile and show "does not contain "a". So you could got illusion that you could not put something in to the map.

```
    Map<String, Integer> tilesMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();   

    Integer increment = 0;
    tilesMap.put("a", increment);
    if (tilesMap.containsKey('a')){
        System.out.println("contain \"a\"");

        int value = tilesMap.get('a');

        // setting the increment value in 'a'

        increment ++;
    }else{
        System.out.println("does not contain \"a\"");
    }
```

Comment: Use Map<Character, Integer>;  tilesMap.put('a', increment);

Comment: ofc, just try to understand the question. It's too easy to ask, so the actual reason could be in some error. Generally we need to see all code, with map initiation to understand the question